# ERROR:"javah" failed to generate header

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have been stuck in this for few days. kindly help me to get rid of this.

**Error is**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class nam
>   e: D:/Android/androidProjects/OpenCV/openCVLibrary/build/intermediates/classes/debug
>   :
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:129)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
>           at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:503)
>           at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:329)
>           at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)

Comment: how are you using it?

Comment: D:\Android\androidProjects\OpenCV>javah -d D:/Android/androidProjects/OpenCV/app/src
/main/jni -classpath D:/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar; D:/Android/and
roidProjects/OpenCV/openCVLibrary/build/intermediates/classes/debug: com.example.ahm
edarif.opencv.DetectionBasedTracker

Comment: `debug:` <-- did you mean to write `;` instead of `:` ?

Comment: no its : "debug:"